# Centering Image in smaller div container with hidden overflow

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm using tailwindcss and trying to determin how can I adjust a container height to be `h-32` on small mobile devices with the image that is within that container have its overflow hidden, but the image adjusted to vertically center within the shrunken div? At the moment the top of the image is present for the smaller device size.

**Code:**

```
<div className='flex flex-col justify-center py-3'>
  <div className='md:mx-auto overflow-hidden h-32 md:h-full'>
    <Image
      src='/hotel-empire.jpeg'
      width={600}
      height={400}
      //   fill={true}
      className='object-cover object-top'
      alt='Test'
    />
  </div>
  <div className='py-3'>
    ...
  </div>
  <div>
    ....
  </div>
</div>
```

**Full Image:**

[image: full size]

**Small Device:**

[image: small device]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider adding `h-32` to the `<Image>` component instead of the parent. Add `max-md:` variant to it so that it only applies up to the `md` breakpoint. Remove `object-top` so that the default `object-position: center` is applied and thus the image inside the `<img>` will be cropped vertically to center.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div class='flex flex-col justify-center py-3'>
  <div class='md:mx-auto overflow-hidden md:h-full relative'>
    <img
      src="https://picsum.photos/600/400"
      width="600"
      height="400"
      class="max-md:h-32 object-cover"
    />
  </div>
  <div class='py-3'>
    ...
  </div>
  <div>
    ....
  </div>
</div>
```